# Lightbox not working on WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, prettyphoto

Could someone please help me find out why the lightbox will not work on my website? I've tried both prettyPhoto and fancyBox (they are pre-installed within the wordpress plugin). The pictures keep linking to the original file.

[Website Link](http://development.pointquack.com/portfolio/)

[Plugin Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-image-gallery/)

I've tried removing the scripts and disabling all other plugins, I have no idea why it's not working. Im sure the plugin is fine, it may just be my theme. I've also tried deleting all functions. I'm using Google Chrome, and I also used Safari.

Thanks

Code (moved from comments) :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        social_tools: false,
        show_title: false
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: F12 for your console (in Chrome). There are errors.

Comment: @Popnoodles I'm not an expert in JS, could you help with these, are they related to the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: I see both `http://development.pointquack.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0` and `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` being loaded, and I'm trying to sort out the order in which each piece of code is being called.

Comment: @JasonAller Thanks, removed one of the jquery's and its working now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have `<a rel="prettyphoto[group]">`but it should be `<a rel="prettyPhoto[group]"></a>` with a capital 'P'